# Spark (Scala), considering days before 2 years ago

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm writing a Spark batch job in Scala and need to filter a dataframe ('driverTable', with column 'date') so that I keep only dates below 2 years ago (discarding all other columns).

```
val dayList: Seq[Date] = driverTable
        .select("date")
        .as[Date]
        .distinct
        .filter(s"date <= ... ")
        .collect()
        .sortBy(_.getTime)
        .toSeq
```

driverTable: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [flowname: string, date: date]

'date' is in java.sql.Date format.

How do I fill .filter? So, if today is 05/25/2021, then I need to filter in all days before 05/25/2019. If February 29, then February 28 of 2 years before is the threshold.

Comment: use a new date object and subtract 2 years from it, the date object has a built in function for that.. and u can use the output for u'r filter. u might need to apply date formatting tho.

Comment: generally speaking.. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446888/how-to-subtract-days-in-scala

Comment: that collect looks dubious...

Comment: @thebluephanton how come?

Comment: What is the `date` format here? Do you use `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`, or something else? Can you edit your question's text to provide an example value of the "date" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deliberately casting your `date` column to `java.sql.Date` and manage it like a Java object, it's safer to convert it to Spark's native date by using `to_date` (Scala docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#to_date(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) where you can optionally specify the date format that is being used in your column with a simple `String` argument (as we will see later on).

After that, all we need to get is:

- the current date of execution, and
- a way to calculate the date difference in years based on `date`

As for the current date, Spark provides `current_timestamp()` (Scala docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#current_timestamp():org.apache.spark.sql.Column)), in which we can enforce our desired date format by encapsulating it within a `date_format` method (Scala docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#date_format(dateExpr:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,format:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) (just like we use `to_date` like we mentioned before).

Now to calculate the difference in years between the current and given date in the `date` column, we can take advantage of the `months_between` methods (Scala docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#months_between(end:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,start:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) that returns the difference of months in `Long` format (both as positive and negative numbers, so we need to get the absolute value of it). You can also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57189953/5644037) answer to get a better look at its usage.

Let's say that we have the following input DataFrame `df` with a `yyyy-MM-dd` date format in the `date` column:

```
+---+----------+
| id|      date|
+---+----------+
|  1|2021-05-25|
|  2|2020-05-26|
|  3|2020-05-20|
|  4|2019-05-26|
|  5|2019-05-10|
+---+----------+
```

All we need to do is specify the date format in `date` and then filter out the rows of `df` by checking if the absolute month difference between the current date and each given date is less than **24** months:

```
df.select("date")
          .withColumn("date", to_date(col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
          .filter(abs(months_between(col("date"), date_format(current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd"))) <= 24)
```

This will result in filtering out the dates that are more than 2 years old from the current date, as seen below:

```
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2021-05-25|
|2020-05-26|
|2020-05-20|
|2019-05-26|
+----------+
```